# how to get cookie from request header using typescript for ionic?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, cookies, ionic-framework

I have just tried a lot but I can't find out the solution for that, I am using JSP Servlet Cookie.

Receiving the cookie in chrome browser but can't retrieve it.
[image]
This is a code I am using:

```
var obj={"Username":this.username,"Password":this.passwor};


var link = "http://xxxxxx";
var myData = JSON.stringify(obj);
var aa="data="+myData;
let headname = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headname, withCredentials: true});
this.http.post(link, aa, options)
.subscribe(res => {
   this.response
      let headers: Headers = res.headers;
      headers.get('Set-Cookie');
});
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8